# Bash variable substitution when using a command line argument file

Tags: bash, variables, substitution

```
FILEDIR=/home/myuserdir/audit
FILE=auditreport.csv
```

The above variable is in my configuration file.

I have this bash script that runs with a configuration file I have:

```
for file in `ls ${FILEDIR}/${FILE}`
```

It does see my path, it is going into the root or `/` directory instead of going into my `/home/myuserdir/audit` dir. But if I declare the variable in the script instead of the configuration file, it works perfectly and the right directory is found. What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately, I have to run the script with the configuration file for easy customization going forward.

I have tried to wrap the statement in `“”`, but it still does not work.

The expected results is I would like for the script to go to `/home/myuserdir/audit` instead of the home directory.

Comment: How does your bash script access its configuration file? How how you're doing that. That seems to be where the problem lies.

Comment: BTW, note that `ls ${FILEDIR}/${FILE}` is buggy, and will break whenever the user has a directory name with spaces, or if you have `IFS` set to contain `/` or another value that can exist inside the names; it should be `ls "$FILEDIR/$FILE"` with the quotes to prevent string-splitting and glob expansion. (Also, all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell and OS; application-defined names should have at least one lower-case character, as defined in the POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, to avoid conflicts).

Comment: ...but yes, to address the real problem, we'd need to see how you're loading the file.

Comment: Note that `for file in $(...)` (either with that newer command-substituition syntax or the older backtick-based one) is also bad practice and bug-prone; see [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: I am loading the file by calling the main script and then the configuration file as in /FileScripts/BashScripts/Audit.sh /FileScripts/ConfigFiles/Audit.config

Comment: @Peadove I don't understand what you mean. Are you running Audit.sh and passing the path to the config file as an argument? If so, what does Audit.sh do with its argument; if not, exactly what are you doing?

Comment: @Peadove : If you really run the config file in the way you stated - you should include this information in your posting - no variables should be visible in the parent shell, because Audit.config would run in a subshell. Also, your loop does not make much sense. Why don't you simply write `file="$FILEDIR/$file"`?

Answer (score 0):

You must source your configfile, not only start it!

**my.config**

```
ConfigFileDir=/home/myuserdir/audit
ConfigFile=auditreport.csv
```

**your script**

```
# source my.config at the top of your script
source my.config

# and use the variables
echo "$ConfigFileDir/$ConfigFile"
```